How to extend the background to the entire webpage?
I set .matrix-background to position: fixed and adjusted width, height, and top properties to make it cover the full page.
I used document.body.scrollHeight in JavaScript to calculate the page height, hoping the animation would cover the entire page.
I want the matrix background on the whole webpage even if i scroll down till the end but i'm only getting the background till the first container
here is my index.html Matrix background
     .matrix-background {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                pointer-events: none;
                z-index: -1;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

and this is my script for the background
        <script>
                   const characters = 
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                    const matrixBackground = document.querySelector('.matrix-background');
    
                    function createMatrix() {
                        const span = document.createElement('span');
                        span.style.position = 'absolute';
                        span.style.color = 'green';
                        span.style.fontSize = '20px';
                        span.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
                        span.style.opacity = Math.random();
                        span.textContent = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
             characters.length));
                
                         const x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
                         span.style.left = `${x}px`;
                         span.style.top = `-${Math.random() * 100}px`;  // Start just 
                above the viewport
                         matrixBackground.appendChild(span);
                
                          // The span falls down to cover the visible viewport and beyond 
           to mimic continuous effect
                           const fallDuration = Math.random() * 3 + 2;
                           span.animate([{ transform: 'translateY(0)' }, { transform: 
             `translateY(${window.innerHeight * 2}px)` }], {
                               duration: fallDuration * 1000,
                              easing: 'linear',
                               iterations: 1,
                              fill: 'forwards',
                          });
                
                          setTimeout(() => {
                               span.remove();
                           }, fallDuration * 1000);
                       }
    
                     setInterval(createMatrix, 100);
                    </script>


This is my about section container that is the second page that i scroll to and to see it i made it transparent but still not getting the full background 

and this is the div container 
 <div id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="about-col-1">
                    <img src="images/user.png" alt="User Photo">
                </div>
                <div class="about-col-2">
                    <h1>About Me</h1>
                    <!-- <p>This is the about section. Here, you can provide a brief introduction or background about yourself or your portfolio.</p> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


this is the css code for that 

 #about {
            background-color: transparent; /* Make background invisible */
            color: green; /* Match text color to matrix color */
            padding: 100px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1; /* Ensure it's above the matrix background */
        }


Try this:
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}


I changed the position in matrix background as absolute before it was fixed but still the background (i mean) the words are only falling till the half of my about section that is my second page after scrolling.

There must be something that you are not showing us that is causing your problem, because as you can see in this snippet, you code works just fine.
Perhaps you need to show us the "container" that you say is blocking the animation from moving with the scroll.
Note: I added a minimal amount of html and css to demonstrate the effect.
Edit: Added OP's new "about" section.


const characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
const matrixBackground = document.querySelector('.matrix-background');

function createMatrix() {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.style.position = 'absolute';
  span.style.color = 'green';
  span.style.fontSize = '20px';
  span.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
  span.style.opacity = Math.random();
  span.textContent = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  
  const x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  span.style.left = `${x}px`;
  span.style.top = `-${Math.random() * 100}px`;  // Start just above the viewport
  matrixBackground.appendChild(span);
  
  // The span falls down to cover the visible viewport and beyond to mimic continuous effect
  const fallDuration = Math.random() * 3 + 2;
  span.animate([{ transform: 'translateY(0)' }, 
    { transform: `translateY(${window.innerHeight * 2}px)` }], 
    {
      duration: fallDuration * 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
      iterations: 1,
      fill: 'forwards',
    }
  );
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    span.remove();
  }, fallDuration * 1000);
}

setInterval(createMatrix, 100);
/* EDIT For your new "about" section */
#about {
  background-color: transparent; /* Make background invisible */
  color: green; /* Match text color to matrix color */
  padding: 100px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; /* Ensure it's above the matrix background */
}

.matrix-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* EDIT Added for demo */
.VeryTall {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  outline: 2px yellow;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
}
<!-- EDIT My best guess at what matrix-background is -->
<div class="matrix-background"> </div>


<!-- EDIT Added for demo -->
<section class="VeryTall">We wish you a merry</section>
<section class="VeryTall">Peter piper picked</section>

<!-- EDIT Added for demo -->
<section class="VeryTall">Before the About section</section>

<!-- EDIT Your new "about" section -->
<div id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="about-col-1">
        <img src="images/user.png" alt="User Photo">
      </div>
      <div class="about-col-2">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <!-- <p>This is the about section. Here, you can provide a brief introduction or background about yourself or your portfolio.</p> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- EDIT Added for demo -->
<section class="VeryTall">After the About</section>




i added my about container's code and it's css code.

If you add those html and css sections to my code snippet, you'll see it still works. You are going to have to do more debugging and testing to figure out what you are doing that is causing the problem that you are seeing. As it is not reproducible with what you are posting here.
